# get telegram dialogflow intergration payload data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to integrate my telegram bot with my dialogflow. but I don't know how to get the payload data like telegram ID, name, etc. in [dialogflow docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/) they never explain this.

Answer (score 1):

after I contact dialogflow Support, we can use `originalRequest` like this

```js
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
let payload = agent.originalRequest;
let firstname = payload.payload.data.from.first_name;
```

this is example of the payload

```js
let payload = {
    "source":"telegram",
    "payload":
    {"data":
      {"message_id":51,
        "from":
        {"username":"thisistelegramusername",
          "id":123455678,
          "first_name":"firstname",
          "last_name":"lastname",
          "language_code":"en"
          },"text":"halo",
          "chat":
          {"id":"123455678",
            "type":"private"},
            "date":1618373981}}}
```